# Laravel Auth::id() return null after login

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

I have a login form to access to my web page.
In my local computer everything works fine. But now I upload my project to my server and when I  login the directive @auth() is null.
I put in my controller this:  dd(Auth::id()); and in my local server returns a Id but in the production server returns null...

in web.php I have tis code:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'role:admin' OR 'role:user'], function () {
    Route::get('/users/inicio', function(){         
    dd(Auth::id());
    return view('frontend.dashboardUser');});   
});
```

This return null

Can you help me?
Thank you

Comment: are you using shared hosting?  in shared hosting this can be a problem with casing. In local environment laravel does it automatically but if you are using shared hosting then you have to make the naming uniform.

Comment: Yes I'm in a shared hosting.  How can I do "you have to make the naming uniform"?

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be some session problem, It might not be maintaining the session state.

My suggestion:

Try `echo session_id()` multiple times, If every time different id is generated then there will be some problem with the session on server otherwise not.

Comment: I put in my function controller: dd(Session::all()); and If I reload this page my _token is changing .... Can you help me? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered a new user after you pushed your code to the production? I mean have you logged in using an existing user on production? I believe your production and local Database is different and the user who exists on local does not exist on production DB.

Register a new user and login as the new user and then try accessing the route to see if you get the auth id.

Answer (score 0):

For a security reason, you can't access the login user or any other session into the web.php file as well as a constructor of the class.

To archive this you can use middleware something like this:

```
public function __construct() {

    $this->middleware(function (Request $request, $next) {
        if (!\Auth::check()) {
            return redirect('/login');
        }
        $this->userId = \Auth::id(); // you can access user id here

        return $next($request);
    });
}
```

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30990556/laravel-5-how-to-add-authuser-id-through-the-constructor) can help you more. Good luck!!!